# In which cases do we need container networks in kubernetes while we already have kubernetes Service?

Tags: kubernetes, istio, cni

Why do we need point-to-point connection between pods while we have workloads abstraction and networking mechanism (Service/kube-proxy/Ingress etc.) over it?

What is the default CNI?
REDACTED: I was confused about this question because I felt like I haven't installed any of popular CNI plugins when I was installing Kubernetes. It turns out Kubernetes defaults to [`kubenet`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/extend-kubernetes/compute-storage-net/network-plugins/)

Btw, I see a lot of overlap features between Istio and container networks. IMO they could achieve identical objectives. The only difference is that Istio is high-level and CNI is low-level and more efficient, is that correct?
REDACTED:Interestingly, istio has [it's own CNI](https://istio.io/latest/docs/setup/additional-setup/cni/)

Answer (score 0):

Kubernetes networking has some requirements:

> pods on a node can communicate with all pods on all nodes without NAT
> agents on a node (e.g. system daemons, kubelet) can communicate with all pods on that node
> pods in the host network of a node can communicate with all pods on all nodes without NAT

and CNI(Container Network Interface) setup a standard interface, all implements(calico, flannel) need follow it.

So it aims to resolve the kubernetes networking.

The `SVC` is different, it's supplied a virtual address to proxy the `pods`, sine `pods` is ephemeral and its ip will changing but the address of `svc` is immutable.

For the `istio`, it's another thing, it make the connection between microservice as infrastructure and pull out this part from business code (think about spring cloud).

Comment: does SVC depend on CNI mechanism? As far as I know SVC works since kubernetes 1.0, what does SVC use for cross-host networking then?

Comment: SVC is only a proxy, for example, a `SVC`'s IP is `10.96.0.1` and there is two pod behind it and with ip `172.18.0.11` and `172.18.0.12`.  then the `kube-proxy` will create `iptables`(default mode) rules to make the route from `10.96.0.1` to `172.18.0.11/172.18.0.12` on every `node`.  so make it works definitely leverage the functionality of `CNI`, but for `SVC` itself, it just a proxy

Comment: so what would happen if two nodes have two pods with the same ip `172.18.0.11`? that would be horrible

Comment: It will never happen, the `pod` in single k8s cluster will assign a unique ip, so no matter which node the pod actually on, that case will not happen

Answer (score 0):

> why do we need point-to-point connection between pods while we have workloads abstraction and networking mechanism(Service/kube-proxy/Ingress etc.) over it?

In general, you will find everything about networking in a cluster in [this documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/networking/). You can find more information about [pod networking](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/networking/#the-kubernetes-network-model):

> Every `Pod` gets its own IP address. This means you do not need to explicitly create links between `Pods` and you almost never need to deal with mapping container ports to host ports. This creates a clean, backwards-compatible model where `Pods` can be treated much like VMs or physical hosts from the perspectives of port allocation, naming, service discovery, load balancing, application configuration, and migration.
>
> Kubernetes imposes the following fundamental requirements on any networking implementation (barring any intentional network segmentation policies):
>
> - pods on a node can communicate with all pods on all nodes without NAT
> - agents on a node (e.g. system daemons, kubelet) can communicate with all pods on that node
>
> Note: For those platforms that support  `Pods`  running in the host network (e.g. Linux):
>
> - pods in the host network of a node can communicate with all pods on all nodes without NAT

Then you are asking:

> what is the default cni?

There is no single default [CNI](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/extend-kubernetes/compute-storage-net/network-plugins/#cni) in a kubernetes cluster. It depends on what type you meet, where and how you set up the cluster etc. As you can see reading [this doc about implementing networking model](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/networking/#how-to-implement-the-kubernetes-networking-model) there are many CNI's available in Kubernetes.

[Istio](https://istio.io/) is a completely different tool for something else. You can't compare them like that. Istio is a [service mesh](https://www.redhat.com/en/topics/microservices/what-is-a-service-mesh) tool.

> Istio extends Kubernetes to establish a programmable, application-aware network using the powerful Envoy service proxy. Working with both Kubernetes and traditional workloads, Istio brings standard, universal traffic management, telemetry, and security to complex deployments.